# Google charts in R Shiny are not working from Rstudio on windows

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I am struggling to run google charts in R Shiny. The following app runs perfectly fine on our local Shiny Server. However, when I run the same code from R Studio on Windows PC, google chart does not appear. Any thought? Thanks!

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(googleVis))

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(

    fluidRow(box(htmlOutput("plot", height = 250)))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)

  output$plot <- renderGvis({ gvisBubbleChart(Fruits, idvar="Fruit", 
                                              xvar="Sales", yvar="Expenses",
                                              colorvar="Year", sizevar="Profit",
                                              options=list(
                                                hAxis='{minValue:75, maxValue:125}')) })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? What goes wrong? It works on my machine

Comment: No error. Just does not show the google chart. It runs fine on my linux machine though. Does it have anything to do with versions of R & Studio?

Comment: you might want to paste the output of sessionInfo() into the question so we can see.

Comment: did you try different browsers ? does it work in the rstudio preview?

Comment: Working good as gold when open the app in browser... Does not work in Rstudio preview... Thanks mate!

Comment: Everything works fine on my machine too. Try to re-install all the packages by deleting them physically from the C drive (or wherever they are located)